# How to prevent Users from transfering their own records

Tags: validation-rule

I want to prevent users from transferring their records to another user. I tried the validation rule

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( OwnerId ), 
    Owner:User.Profile.Name ='Profile'`
```

and it works when they are trying to transfer to that profile but not a system admin or any other profile.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator'
)
```

This will forbid user without the sys admin profile to edit the owner field.

Comment: I want to forbid only that profile. The others should be able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your Owner:User.Profile.Name ='Profile' part
is indicating that that's the profile they're changing TO, ie the new owner.  So it will prevent EVERYONE from changing ownership to someone with that profile.

If you mean to be checking the current user's profile use  PRIORVALUE() to get the owner before the change.

Comment: Can you write an example so I can see please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Profile that does not have the Transfer Ownership permission, and then assign those users to that Profile. They will no longer be able to transfer any records. Or, you can create a Page Layout, set the Read Only property on the Owner field, and then assign that Page Layout to the Profile you'd like to restrict access for. Either solution will work without a Validation Rule.